# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404, After CORS enabled also

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I have hosted my webAPI service. and my webConfig.

```
<httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
```

But, when i access this service.

```
1.  General 
1.  Request URL: http://localhost:62007/api/Orders/?$select=OrderID,EmployeeID,CustomerID&params=[object%20Object]
2.  Request Method: OPTIONS
3.  Status Code: 400 Bad Request
4.  Remote Address: [::1]:62007

2.  Response Headers
1.  Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*
2.  Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
3.  Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
4.  Cache-Control:no-cache
5.  Content-Length:98
6.  Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
7.  Date:Fri, 10 Feb 2017 11:22:33 GMT
8.  Expires:-1
9.  Pragma:no-cache
10. Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0
11. X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
12. X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
13. X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?RDpcU2FtcGxlXE1WQ1xHcmlkV2ViQXBpXEdyaWRXZWJBcGlcYXBpXE9yZGVyc1w=?=

3.  Request Headers
1.  Accept:*/*
2.  Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
3.  Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
4.  Access-Control-Request-Headers:dataserviceversion, maxdataserviceversion
5.  Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
6.  Connection:keep-alive
7.  Host:localhost:62007
8.  Origin:http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com
9.  Referer:http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/wqtmoa3v
10. User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
```

When i access the resource from http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com, i got the following error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400
>   (Bad Request) VM2343 djbei0ge:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:62007/api/Orders/?$select=OrderID,EmployeeID,CustomerID&params=[object%20Object].
>   Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400

Please help me out to fix this issue.

Comment: Take a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this chrome extension 
"Allow-Control-Allow-Origin"

also this page might help 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors

if all didn't work for you you might want to use IE because some of the CORS problems are only on chrome